# ActiveRecord Validation Passing Null instead of Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to integrate Facebook login into my website.

I've built the model like this so far (I can add a better email validator):

```
class FBUser < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :access_token, :expires_in, :reauthorize_in
    attr_reader :email, :fb_id

    validates :fb_id, :email, :access_token, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: true
    validates :access_token, :expires_in, :reauthorize_in, presence: true

end
```

When a user logs in with Facebook, it passes the returned parameters to this in-development controller function:

```
def fb_login
   params[:email] ||= params[:userID][-7...-1] + "@facebook.com"
   fb_user = FBUser.create({
   fb_id: params[:userID],
   email: params[:email],
   access_token: params[:accessToken],
   expires_in: params[:expiresIn],
   reauthorize_in: params[:reauthorize_required_in]
  })
  sign_in!(fb_user)
  render json: fb_user
end
```

All of those params are present but when it does the validations during the create it passes NULL for the email and fb_id.
From the Rails output:

> FBUser Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "fb_users" WHERE "fb_users"."fb_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>
> FBUser Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "fb_users" WHERE "fb_users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>
> FBUser Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "fb_users" WHERE "fb_users"."access_token" = 'EAAEDVcUvjT4BACT8es...
>
> SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "fb_users" ("fb_id", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["fb_id", "101564XXXXXXX688"], ["email", "XXXX68@facebook.com"], ["created_at", "2018-08-17 02:42:20.440539"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-17 02:42:20.440539"]]

I know it is the uniqueness validation because if I remove it those queries go away. As it is, the uniqueness validation is not doing anything. I don't know why the access token is not being passed to the INSERT statement at all, but this is a secondary issue.

I've passed the "param[]" parameters into a variable and that did nothing. I'm stumped as to why it is passing in NULL for the uniqueness check instead of the values for email and fb_id, but not the access token. It passes the values in the INSERT being called from the same create method right afterwards!

I was creating multiple FBUsers with the same fb_id and email, but the table was created as:

```
create_table :fb_users do |t|
      t.string :fb_id, null: false, unique: true
      t.string :email, unique: true
      t.string :access_token ...
```

More strangeness...

Comment: Can you debug and paste the `params` you're getting back before the `FBUser.create`

Comment: They're included in the INSERT INTO statement, they are the same beforehand.

Comment: Can you please edit the above question with your additional information.

Comment: But your `INSERT INTO` does not have the column `access_token` or any of the other columns after that, it just shows `email` and `fb_id`

Comment: The necessary params that are being used in the create method are present, we do not need to investigate that.

Comment: Ok. Did you check for errors in the object ? `fb_user.errors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord attributes (i.e. columns that are stored in the database) are not the same as instance variables. You have this:

```
attr_reader :email, :fb_id
```

in your model. That's just shorthand for:

```
def email
  @email
end

def fb_id
  @fb_id
end
```

so whenever someone says `fbuser.email` or `fbuser.fb_id`, you'll be looking at the instance variables. But, when you say:

```
FBUser.create({
  fb_id: params[:userID],
  email: params[:email],
  ...
})
```

ActiveRecord will call the `fb_id=` and `email=` methods store those two values in the model instance. ActiveRecord creates those mutator methods for you and they will update *attributes*, not *instance variables*. Normally AR would also create `fb_id` and `email` methods to read those attributes but you've already created those methods with your `attr_reader` call.

The result is that `fbuser.email` will read from `@email` but `fbuser.email = something` will write to something else and so `fbuser.email` will always give you `nil`. Similarly for `fbuser.fb_id`.

You probably want to get rid of the `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` calls completely and make your model look like this:

```
class FBUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :fb_id, :email, :access_token, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: true
  validates :access_token, :expires_in, :reauthorize_in, presence: true
end
```

Comment: That's it! I was going overkill with my attrs thinking about the model because at some point (maybe while the user is logged in) the access_token may expire and need to be changed. A fundamental mistake with very subtle repercussions.